# useState setter not updating array immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to develop a todo app in react. below is the code.
when I enter todo in the textbox and click to add, then the todos is giving old value.
For eg. if I enter "a", then todos array give `[]`, then when I enter "b" todos display `["a"]`. please help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Todo() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  function changeHandler(e) {
    // console.log(e.target.value)
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  // this doesn't update todos and moreover logs infinitely
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setTodos([...todos]);
  // }, [todos]);

  function handleClick() {
    setTodos([...todos, value]);
    console.log(todos);
    setValue("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        placeholder="Add Todo"
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Todo</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Todo;
```

**Edit:**

Below worked

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(todos);
  }, [todoList]);

  function handleClick() {
    setTodos([...todos, value]);
    setValue("");
  }
    // console.log(todos);

  return (
    ...
}
export default Todo;
```

Comment: `setTodos` is async, you cannot log the value right below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state in React is an asynchronous operation, if you want to log the state of your state, you should use `useEffect`.

```js
// Don't setTodos in an useEffect for todos since it will result in an infinite loop.
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(todos)
}, [todos]);
```

Comment: So what do you do if you need a change to be immediate? Like for example, when I click the Submit button, I need to immediately show a spinner, rather than wait for `setLoading` and then check `loading` on render.

Answer (score 0):

The setting state is asynchronous.
When use setTodos or setValues it causes a re-render in your flow.

Move you console to Todo scope function. Like this:

```
...
function handleClick() {
  setTodos([...todos, value]);
  setValue("");
}

console.log(todos);

return (
...
```

The code below causes a loop because your *useEffect* are listening to all changes in `todos` and you are `setTodos` on more time.

```
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setTodos([...todos]);
  // }, [todos]);
```